# How are bank accounts linked to other accounts?

Tags: bank-account, transfer, electronic-payment

How do services like Square link bank accounts to people's personal accounts? Is there some API they're plugging into? Is this the same as ACH?

Answer (score 6):

> Is this the same as ACH?

It's not "the same as ACH", it **is** ACH. All the transfers to and from your bank accounts to Square/PayPal/other bank accounts go through ACH. The exception is wire-transfer, which goes in a different (and much faster, and more expensive) route.

Comment: What's the other route called? Is there a website that describes exhaustively these routes? Who controls them?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Worldwide_Interbank_Financial_Telecommunication